# Qt: QGraphicsVideoItem not expanding to largest possible size

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I'm trying to load a 720p video with a `QGraphicsVideoItem` in a `QGraphicsView`, but the output is no where near the size. How do I get it to stretch to the maximum size possible (based on window size)?
MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtMultimedia as qtm
from PySide6 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmw

app = qtw.QApplication()
view = qtw.QGraphicsView()
scene = qtw.QGraphicsScene()
video_item = qtmw.QGraphicsVideoItem()
scene.addItem(video_item)
view.setScene(scene)
view.fitInView(video_item, qtc.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
media_player = qtm.QMediaPlayer()
media_player.setVideoOutput(video_item)
media_player.setSource("video_file")
media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(media_player.play)
view.show()
app.exec()
```

This is what it looks like in a 960/1080-ish window:

[image]

Comment: [QGraphicsView.fitInView()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-2)

Comment: @ekhumoro Apologies, I should have mentioned this but that didn't work either. I updated the code in OP accordingly.

Comment: Works fine for me. You obviously need to explicitly initialise both the window size and [the video size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html#size-prop) first (e.g. `video_item.setSize(view.viewport().size())`). And whatever resizing method you use also needs to be called in the resize-event handler, if the window is resizeable.

Comment: @ekhumoro so I tried what you suggested, it works fine, but when I go fullscreen on i3 (with mod + F) I get vertical scrollbars. I don't get the scroll bars if I comment out the `video_item.setSize` line though. [Here's the code.](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/7b0428a7/) What do you think could be causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce that using an openbox wm on arch-linux. I suspect you may be prone to some [X11 Peculiarities](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities). You could try commenting out `super().resizeEvent(event)`, as it's not really needed, and also setting an explicit geometry in `View.__init__` (i.e. before any other resizing is done). However, I think this may be due to the change in frame-geometry not being taken into account in full-sreen mode. Presumably the scrollbar offset is quite small - i.e. about the width of the frame + title-bar?

Comment: One hack that sometimes works with issues like this, is to make an asynchronous adjustment following the relevant [window-state change](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindowstatechangeevent.html). So try overriding [changeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#changeEvent) and call `fitInView` with a single-shot timer whenever the [Qt.WindowFullScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowState-enum) state occurs. (You may need to experiment with the timer delay in order for this to have any effect).

Comment: @ekhumoro used the `singleShot` way and [this](https://paste.debian.net/1255968/) works now. As for your suggestions in the first comment, none of those worked. Guess I'll just stick with this hack for now, thank you.